# Liferay with Activiti Example

Tags: java, liferay-6, activiti

Where can i found a working n level activiti workflow integrated into the liferay.

I have searched in the google but i could not get any working example..

Activiti integrated with Liferay 6 using Tomcat...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find activiti-web war which can be found in below link,

http://www.emforge.net/web/activiti-liferay

You will need activiti designer plugin for eclipse where you can create a workflow and then xml which is BPMN 2.0

http://www.emforge.net/web/activiti-liferay/wiki/-/wiki/Main/BPMN+2.0+for+Liferay+with+using+Activiti+Plugin

For detail understanding of activiti you can refer below user guide

http://www.activiti.org/userguide/

Comment: great it helped a lot